Drag and drop feature on SDL2
i want to be able to drag an image file, drop it on the window and have it rendered exactly where the cursor is. problem is, SDL_GetMouseState() stops recording mouse events when I'm dragging the desired file, so it gets rendered on the last recorded cursor position (which is on the edge my cursor went out the window of to fetch the file). is using the Windows API the only solution ? i'd rather not deal with OS compatibility issues right now.
vector<pair<SDL_Texture*, SDL_Rect>> texturePairs;

pair < SDL_Texture*, SDL_Rect> loadTexture(const char* path, int rectX, int rectY) {
    bool success = true;

    SDL_Texture* loadedTexture = IMG_LoadTexture(gRenderer, path);
    if (loadedTexture == NULL) {
        cout << "Could not load texture :" << IMG_GetError() << endl;
        success = false;
        return { NULL, {} };
    }
    else {
        SDL_Rect destRect = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        SDL_QueryTexture(loadedTexture, NULL, NULL, &destRect.w, &destRect.h);
        destRect.x = rectX;
        destRect.y = rectY;
        cout << "rect x,y:" << rectX << "," << rectY << endl;
        texturePairs.push_back(make_pair(loadedTexture, destRect));

        return { loadedTexture, destRect };
    }
}

// game loop in main
while (gameRunning) {
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
        int mouseX, mouseY;
        SDL_GetMouseState(&mouseX, &mouseY);

        switch (event.type) {
            case SDL_QUIT:
                gameRunning = false;
                cout << "User requested exit." << endl;
                break;
            case SDL_MOUSEMOTION:
                lastMouseX = event.motion.x;
                lastMouseY = event.motion.y;
                cout << "last x,y:" << lastMouseX << "," << lastMouseY << endl;
                break;
            case SDL_DROPFILE: {
                char* dropped_filedir = event.drop.file;
                loadTexture(dropped_filedir, mouseX, mouseY);
                currentState = RESIZING_IMAGE;
                SDL_free(dropped_filedir);
                break;
            }

on the console, i get printed out last x,y as the last known cursor position after it goes beyond the window bounds (so it's 0,xxx if it goes out the left side), then after i drop the wanted file it prints out rect x,y identical to the first one which is no longer valid, the image gets rendered there, then it prints out a last x,y with the actual valid position.

Wait until the next frame to get the new coords? Or use SDL_GetGlobalMouseState perhaps.

@HolyBlackCat wouldn't it introduce more latency ? waiting till the next frame can also be problematic if the user moves quickly after the event. i've already tried globalmousestate and its even weirder than the regular one, it doesn't even render it on the last known position.

I think it won't be noticeable in practice. As for SDL_GetGlobalMouseState, it returns the absolute coords that you'd need to manually convert to the window coords.

@HolyBlackCat went with the second fix and now works. used SDL_GetWindowPosition to get the offsets then rendered to the absolute coords minus the offsets. very simple really. thanks !
